# Perfect groups whose character degrees square divide its order and are not prime-power

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters, gap

This post is a sequel of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4574792/84284).

**Question**: Is there a finite perfect group $G$ such that for all (non-trivial) irreducible complex character $\chi$ then $\chi(1)^2$ divides $|G|$ and $\chi(1)$ is not a prime-power?

The post mentioned above got [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4574920/84284) containing a construction starting from the simple group $A_5$ whose character degrees are $[[1,1],[3,2],[4,1],[5,1]]$, and finishing with a perfect group $G$ with character degrees $$
[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 7 ], [ 10, 4 ], [ 12, 10 ], [ 15, 14 ],  [ 20, 59 ], [ 30, 164 ], [ 60, 2651 ] ]$$
Observe that the character degrees of $G$ are multiples of the ones of $A_5$. If this happens also by starting from an other simple group, then I suggest to try with $A_7$ whose character degress are $[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 10, 2 ], [ 14, 2 ], [ 15, 1 ], [ 21, 1 ], [ 35, 1 ] ]$, i.e. no prime-power. But it is not clear to me how to make above construction from $A_7$ in practice (assuming that my expectation is true).

A positive answer to this question will answer a problem in the theory of fusion rings.

Comment: The construction is identical, just adding modules underneath. The question about the degrees is the issue. Using Clifford theory, one has to compute the orbit lengths on the modules, and if none is a prime power then we are good, since all character degrees will be products of degrees for the quotient and these orbit lengths. I could come up with such an example, it shouldn't be too hard, but it might take a day or two. How important is the question from fusion rings? (Or someone else might easily see an example.)

Comment: @DavidA.Craven In a paper which should be on arxiv on Monday (where I cite your previous construction), I asked whether there is a non-trivial perfect integral 1/2-Frobenius fusion ring without (non-trivial) basis element of prime-power FPdim. A negative answer would prove that every simple integral fusion category is weakly group-theoretical, which one of the most famous open statement in fusion category theory. But I realized today that your construction from $A_7$ (instead of $A_5$) should provide a positive answer to my question (making above famous statement still open).

Comment: So I hesitate to update my paper before it appears on arxiv. It will depend on whether it works with $A_7$.

Comment: Are you fixed on $A_7$ for a reason, except that there are no prime-power degree representations? I suggest the sporadic group $J_1$ might be a better choice. Since it has trivial Schur multiplier the Clifford theory is simpler. Its character degrees are 1,56,76,77,120,133,209.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I am not fixed on $A_7$, it was just the smaller one. There are also $M_{22}$, $J_1$, $M_{23}$, etc... So yes, $J_1$ is ok for me.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Just realized there may be some confusion between what you mean and what I mean by fusion. Yours is in the sense of fusion systems in finite group theory, while mine is in the sense of tensor categories (see [this book](https://math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf) by P. Etingof, S. Gelaki, D. Nikshych and V. Ostrik). Do you know a connection between the two concepts?

Comment: I know that fusion rings are different from fusion systems, but thanks for checking. (There has been confusion from some people before in assigning referees...) I guess the question was that I can (probably) make such a group, but it would require some thought as to proving that the group exists (it would be too big to construct probably) and so if it's just idle curiosity then I wouldn't bother, but if it didn't something good then I would.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: if you can make such a group (or prove its existence), then it would answer positively Question 1.9 in my today's paper [arXiv:2302.01613](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.01613), where you are cited just before. If such a group does not exist, then it would be a good clue for a negative answer to Q.1.9, and then for that every simple integral modular fusion category is pointed, which would solve the famous Question 2 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2010.06.009) by ENO, in the simple case, thanks to Theorem 5.8 in [arXiv:2102.01663](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.01663).